# connect to external sql server using pyodbc and FreeTDS drivers on rhel 7 linux

Tags: pyodbc, freetds

I have an AWS EC2 instance, installed FreeTDS, I run osql and it tells me Configuration looks ok but then does an isql. That fails.  I tried the tsql -LH  but nothing returned.  tsql -S  returns:
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20009 (severity 9):
        Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
There was a problem connecting to the server

Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the full `tsql` command you're using? Are you using `odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` for DSNs, or FQDNs? Welcome to S.O.!

Comment: tsql -S <server ip> _-U <userid> -P <password>

Comment: This is my odbcinst.ini [FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS Driver v0.91                                           Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0